# android cant send 3 encoded string from base64 to mysql using json

Tags: android, mysql, json, base64

i do simple project which encode 3 photos to String using base 64 and i want to send that 3 encoded strings to MySQL and i am using . i have tried sent 1 and 2 encoded string and it was succeed, i don't know why when i try sent 3 encoded string there is an error like this.

```
06-17 08:03:37.837  11479-11703/com.example.indraaaeff.e_fine2 E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

is there a limitation for sending encoded string from android to mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

The error mentions `<br` not being able to be encoded. "<" is an special character, is not base64 and it should be escaped with "\". Make sure you are actually encoding a valid base64 string and not unescaped HTML.